# Bad state: No ProviderScope found in flutter consumer component

Tags: flutter

When I add flutter consumer component in flutter like this:

```
SliverPadding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        sliver: Consumer(
                              (context, read) {
                            return read(storiesTypeProvider(articleRequest)).when(
                              loading: () {
                                // return SliverFillRemaining(
                                // child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                                return SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: LoadingItem()));
                              },
                              error: (err, stack) {
                                print(err);
                                return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                                    child: Center(child: Text('Error: $err')));
                              },
                              data: (ids) {


                                //return StoryList(ids: ids,storiesType: articleRequest.storiesType,);
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
```

shows this error:

```
flutter: [debug] Capture from onError 'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 806 pos 14: 'position.hasContentDimensions && position.hasPixels': is not true.
flutter: [debug] Capture from onError 'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 806 pos 14: 'position.hasContentDimensions && position.hasPixels': is not true.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#0ac5b](state: RawGestureDetectorState#734b4(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
Bad state: No ProviderScope found

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SmartRefresher file:///Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/lib/src/page/home/components/homelistdefault_component/view.dart:47:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ProviderStateOwnerScope.of (package:flutter_riverpod/src/framework.dart:216:7)
#1      _ConsumerState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:107:46)
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4839:11)
#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4655:5)
...     Normal element mounting (4 frames)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 806 pos 14: 'position.hasContentDimensions && position.hasPixels': is not true.
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 806 pos 14: 'position.hasContentDimensions && position.hasPixels': is not true.
====================================================================================================
```

now I am using `fish-redux` to manage my flutter state, should I must using `ProviderScope`? what should I do to fix this problem? this is the `storiesTypeProvider`:

```
final storiesTypeProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, type) async {
  return await Repo.getArticles(type);
});
```

Comment: Consumer the missing a type argument: Consumer<TypeItMustConsume>

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you use  flutter_riverpod.
You need to add ProviderScope to the main() function.
Like this:

```
void main() {
   runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}
```

Comment: I already had `ProviderScope` there but it didn't work. But when I moved the `ProviderScope` to within `MyApp()`, wrapping `MaterialApp`, it worked.

Comment: @Giraldi same thing happened to me ... did you find any reason why it forced us to wrap `MaterialApp` instead of `MyApp()`?

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon I haven't figured that out yet. Have been working on another project that does not use that.

Answer (score 2):

i searched for the solution and i dont get it on youtube and on chatgpt and here on stackoverflow   ,i tryed to see  flutter_riverpod version on pub.dev and i see it  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6  ,,me i use  flutter_riverpod: ^2.1.3 before upgrading to  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6

just upgrade your    ( flutter_riverpod )  to the latest
now its       flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6
this fix me the problem

Comment: You just need to wrap the app with a ProviderScope and that's it.